# PhalconPHP & ACL: guests were able to access restricted content

Tags: acl, phalcon

I don't want to allow guest **phones/new**. They should have access for **phones/index** and one other thing only. But guests were able to access all actions of **Phones** controller. I need your help to find out the mistake I did.

Here is the ACL plugin

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Acl;
use Phalcon\Acl\Role;
use Phalcon\Acl\Resource;
use Phalcon\Events\Event;
use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher;
use Phalcon\Acl\Adapter\Memory as AclList;

/**
 * SecurityPlugin
 *
 * This is the security plugin which controls that users only have access to the modules they're assigned to
 */
class SecurityPlugin extends Plugin
{

    /**
     * Returns an existing or new access control list
     *
     * @returns AclList
     */
    public function getAcl()
    {


        if (!isset($this->persistent->acl)) {

            $acl = new AclList();

            $acl->setDefaultAction(Acl::DENY);

            //Register roles
            $roles = array(
                'admin' => new Role('Admin'),
                'editor' => new Role('Editor'),
                'guests' => new Role('Guests')
            );

            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                $acl->addRole($role);
            }

            //Admin area resources
            $adminResources = array(
                'dashboard' => array('index'),
                'phones' => array('index', 'all', 'new', 'edit', 'save', 'create', 'delete', 'search'),
                'users' => array('index', 'search', 'new', 'edit', 'save', 'create', 'delete', 'saveProfile', 'profile'),
            );

            foreach ($adminResources as $resource => $actions) {
                $acl->addResource(new Resource($resource), $actions);
            }

            //Editor area resources
            $editorResources = array(
                'dashboard' => array('index'),
                'phones' => array('index', 'all', 'new', 'edit', 'save', 'create', 'search'),
                'users' => array('saveProfile', 'profile'),
            );

            foreach ($editorResources as $resource => $actions) {
                $acl->addResource(new Resource($resource), $actions);
            }


            //Public area resources
            $publicResources = array(
                'index' => array('index'),
                'about' => array('index'),
                'login' => array('index', 'check', 'logout'),
                'errors' => array('show404', 'show500'),
                'contact' => array('index', 'send'),
                'phones' => array('index', 'search'),
            );
            foreach ($publicResources as $resource => $actions) {
                $acl->addResource(new Resource($resource), $actions);
            }

            //Grant access to public areas to both users and guests
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                foreach ($publicResources as $resource => $actions) {
                    $acl->allow($role->getName(), $resource, '*');
                }
            }

            //Grant access to private area to role Admin
            foreach ($adminResources as $resource => $actions) {
                foreach ($actions as $action) {
                    $acl->allow('Admin', $resource, $action);
                }
            }

            //Grant access to private area to role Admin
            foreach ($editorResources as $resource => $actions) {
                foreach ($actions as $action) {
                    $acl->allow('Editor', $resource, $action);
                }
            }

            //The acl is stored in session, APC would be useful here too
            $this->persistent->acl = $acl;
        }

        return $this->persistent->acl;
    }

    /*
     * This action is executed before execute any action in the application
     *
     * @param Event $event
     * @param Dispatcher $dispatcher
     */
    public function beforeDispatch(Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher)
    {

        $auth = $this->session->get('auth');

        if (!$auth) {
            $role = 'Guests';
        } else {
            switch ($auth['role']) {
                case 1:
                    $role = "Admin";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $role = "Editor";
                    break;
                default:
                    $role = "Guests";
                    break;
            }
        }

        $controller = $dispatcher->getControllerName();
        $action = $dispatcher->getActionName();

        $acl = $this->getAcl();

        $allowed = $acl->isAllowed($role, $controller, $action);
        if ($allowed != Acl::ALLOW) {
            $dispatcher->forward(array(
                'controller' => 'errors',
                'action' => 'show401'
            ));
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At adding the public resources: won't `$acl->allow($role->getName(), $resource, '*');` allow to access any action in the resource due to the wildcard.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. I was new and copied from Invo. However thanks for reply.

Comment: Could you put that up as an answer and accept it? I came here because I thought you needed help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing wildcard to specific action. I actually copied code from invo and overlooked the thing.

```
//Grant access to public areas to both users and guests
foreach ($roles as $role) {
    foreach ($publicResources as $resource => $actions) {
        $acl->allow($role->getName(), $resource, $actions);
    }
}
```